# What's going wrong in My Visual studio ? and how can I run my project now [alternate solution]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ASP.NET MVC project and they work fine for me and I have no problem with them in Visual studio but now I have a issue that how can I debug the project in Visual studio?

I install `productivity power tool` in Visual studio because I already open many other I just point both [two file who I need] and close all other and they work.

When I move from one to put them as vertically I find that Visual studio goes crashed. later I am trying with many things but never found that's work. i try with boot, with safe mode, with disable all plugins but nothing found that's work for me.

when I debug the project I can IIS icon on the taskbar but i wait for a long time but page not display. first I thing it's database issue but their is no fault their.

later I investigate many thing but never found that's work. the problem is when I debug the project the firefox unable to show my page. I wait for long time [15 minutes] and later I found a error that.

Firefox unable to connect. Chrome and IE give same error. so can anyone show me what thing I need to do it's work.

log of VS:
yesterday I install MVC3 update, update WPI and webmatrix [I hope no relation with it] it's just happend because my visual studio goes crashed.

can anyone tell me the way I can use. now my visual studio work perfect for me. nothing I found wrong after the crash [I think it's like plane crash for me because it's my day boring and useless]

so their is no problem I found later crash of visual studio but debugging not worked. for testing i test with blogengine.net sample project I have and they are debug correctly. so I think that something goes wrong with the project I have onyl.

How can I solve this issue?

Edit

---

Today after installing `productivity power tool` my visual studio crashed and later I found that my project not deug.  I try with safe mode, disable plugin, reboot system and the all thing need to make it work.

When I debug blogengine.net project I found that 's work.

When I debug mine project I found that's not debug. it's debug and I wait in browser 15 minute bug it's not show me anything.

What I do now that my Visual studio works

Comment: I have hard time following your explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the LOOONG question that is not clarifying the problem well, It's not clear whether the main cause of this problem is a plugin or the runtime itself.

the easiest way(and longest) is to uninstall your VS completely and reinstall with default settings, and just after the successful install, use web platform installer or the setup file to install MVC3.

then you may start your project and check if it's working and debugging just fine or not, and let's know what happened with you.